# analysing errors accrued while uploading files into API in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to analyse the errors which accrue while our clients trying to upload their files to our plate form, not sure if that even possible using PostgreSQL.

My table has three columns `company_id`,`import_id` and `operation_errors`.

I tried this query which worked perfectly on rows which have one error but in most cases, I have more than 3 errors per import, my query picked the first only the first one when there more.

```
SELECT importable_id ,
       importable_type ,
       substring(lower(replace_operation)
                 FROM 'title:(.+?)detail:') test
FROM
  ( SELECT import_id ,
           importable_id ,
           i.importable_type ,
           operation_errors  as replace_operation
   FROM import_results ir
   JOIN imports i ON ir.import_id = i.id
   WHERE operation_errors IS NOT NULL
     AND i.created_at >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE :: date)) a
WHERE importable_type = 'Company';
```

as I said the row might have one or more errors here is one example of the errors  Msg

```
      ---
      - !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        code: 314
      title: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
        detail: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxx. i.e 21 February, 2018.
     source: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      pointer: "/data/attributes/xxxxxxx"
      - !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       code: 343
        title: xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx
     detail: xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx.
     source: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     pointer: "/data/attributes/xxxxxxxxxxx"
    - !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::             
     code: 342
      title: xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx
    detail: xxxxxx xx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx
    xxxxxxxxx     x xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxx xx xx.
      source: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::xxxxxxxxxxx
     pointer: "/data/attributes/xxxxxxxxxx"
```

i am hoping to have somthing like this

```
      importable_id errore1         errore 2        errore 3
       1           title: xxxxx.    title: xxxxx.   title: xxxxx.
       2           title: xxxxx.        
       3           itle: xxxxx.      title: xxxxx.
```

I also tried

```
       split_part(replace_operation, ' ', 1) AS col1
```

but i end up with 40 column and still didn't get all the errors in some rows

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find an answer to my question thank @Andyk

```
WITH errors AS
  (SELECT importable_id ,
          importable_type,
          created_at ,
          substring(lower(replace_operation)
                    FROM 'code:(.+?)title') code_1 ,
          split_part(replace_operation, 'code', 2) AS code_2 ,
          split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 2) AS sec_part ,
          split_part(split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 2), ':', 2) error_1 ,
          split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 3) AS third_part ,
          split_part(split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 3), ':', 2) error_2 ,
          split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 4) AS f_part ,
          split_part(split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 4), ':', 2) error_3 ,
          split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 5) AS f_part ,
          split_part(split_part(replace_operation, 'title', 5), ':', 2) error_4
   FROM
     ( SELECT import_id ,
              importable_id ,
              i.importable_type ,
              operation_errors AS replace_operation,
              i.created_at
      FROM import_results ir
      JOIN imports i ON ir.import_id = i.id
      WHERE operation_errors IS NOT NULL
        AND i.created_at >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE :: date)) a
   WHERE importable_type = 'Company')
SELECT importable_id,
       created_at::date ,
       code_1 ,
       error_1 ,
       error_2 ,
       error_3 ,
       error_4
FROM errors
```